# English Premier League Standings, Overall Record

Tags: r

I am trying to create standings with the current data for teams in the English Premier League. I am using the current season data found here http://www.football-data.co.uk/englandm.php . I am attempting to do this using a for loop, however, I am a newb and do not really know what I am doing.

"H" stands for home win, "A" away win, and "D" draw. If anyone could help me get the overall record and standings I would be grateful. 
Here is my code so far:

```
read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/E0.csv")

dfmess <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/E0.csv")

e.dates <- as.Date(c("8/8/2015", "9/8/2015","14/08/15", "15/08/15"
                     , "16/08/15", "17/08/15", "22/08/15", "23/08/15", "24/08/15", "29/08/15", "30/08/15", "12/09/2015"
                     , "13/09/15", "14/09/15", "19/09/15", "20/09/15", "26/09/15", "27/09/15", "28/09/15"), format = %m/%d/%y)

# formatting issue with the dates here. 


dfmess[dfmess$FTR == "H", c(3,7)] #list of all HomeTeam Wins
dfmess[dfmess$FTR == "A", c(4,7)] #list of all AwayTeam wins
dfmess[dfmess$FTR == "D", c(3:4,7)] #list of all Draws

x <-3

for (i in dfmess(dfmess[1:71, c(3:4,7)])){
  if dfmess[dfmess$FTR == "H", c(3,7)]
  x <- 1
  sum(x)
  print(dfmess[dmessf$HomeTeam == sum(x)])  #Trying to get standings, but lost. 
}else{
  same for "A"
}else{
  same for "D"
}
```